# Why does \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math} not work?

Tags: fontspec, mac, tex-gyre-math

With XeLaTeX, the following source works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\setmathfont{texgyrebonum-math.otf} % this way OK
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math} % but this way gives "font cannot be found" error

\begin{document}
\[
\int_{0}^{1} e^{-\frac{1}{2} \xi^{2}} d \xi
\]
\end{document}
```

However, if I comment out the line

```
\setmathfont{texgyrebonum-math.otf}
```

and uncomment the line

```
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
```

then I get error

```
Package fontspec Error: The font "TeX Gyre Bonum Math" cannot be found.
```

The latter, "verbose", form of specifying the math font does work, however, with TeX Gyre Pagella Math and TeX Gyre Termes Math.

Command

```
otfinfo -a `kpsewhich texgyrebonum-math.otf`
```

gives the expected result `TeX Gyre Bonum Math`. And

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf
```

already includes the line:

```
<dir>/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: works okay for me. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, I had just used the TeX Live Utility before trying to compile the source. And of course file `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math` is there (otherwise, the form with `texgyrebonum-math.otf` surely would not have worked).

Comment: oh unix. Using font names doesn't work for fonts in the texmf tree unless you have added the tree to your fontconfig.

Comment: My `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf` already includes the line `<dir>/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>`.

Comment: Solved: I needed to add file `texgyrebonum-math.otf` to the macOS system fonts (using Font Book). I didn't realize (or didn't remember) that an OpenType font has to be made known to the OS if it is to be referred to by font name rather than by file name.